# GCM/Parse push function works when using string literal but not string variable

Tags: php, laravel, parse-platform

Bit of a weird one, trying to use Parse to push notifications to a device by deviceToken.

If I specify the deviceToken literally, i.e.

```
$query->equalTo("deviceToken", "uniquedevicetoken");
```

or

```
$token = "uniquedevicetoken";
$query->equalTo("deviceToken", $token);
```

The push works fine without a hitch.

However, If I attempt to use the token from the database, i.e

```
$query->equalTo("deviceToken", $user->gcm_regid);
```

The function is not called, even though if I echo out the raw string and the variable together they appear identical.

Also I tried strcmp() which returns 2.

So even though the characters appear visually identical, one works and one does not.

The tokens are stored in MySQL, I have tried VARCHAR and TEXT with a few different encondings, same result every time.

Comment: Try var_dump('uniquedevicetoken' == $user->gcm_regid);

Comment: Returns false. bool(false)

Comment: That may have helped me find it though.

My variable was two characters longer than the raw text, i think there were some hidden characters at the end. /r/n possibly?

Comment: Very possible. Try $chars = str_split($user->gcm_regid); foreach ($chars as $char) {echo ord($char) . ' ';}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The good solution would be to write in the database "gcm_regid" w/o "special" characters, because it always makes sense to care about sanitization before, so the database will stay "clean". But as a fast solution you can try this:

```
$query->equalTo("deviceToken", rtrim($user->gcm_regid));
```

Comment: I used rtrim to sanitize the reg id before it was inserted to the db and that's fixed it. Thanks!